# How do I fire an event inside an Angular10 app with RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am starting out with Angular10.  I've written a Canvas and can draw on it.  Lets call the thing I draw on the canvas a Foobar --- my Angular10 drawing code of Foobars work fine.  I am getting a Foobar from a REST call using HttpClient and that works fine too because it populates this.foobar when I do the REST call.  What I want to do is make the Canvas observe the this.foobar 'model' so that when this.foobar changes, then the Canvas redraws the Foobar.

Does this mean I make the Foobar an Observable with RxJS?  If so how do I do that? Then this.foobar.subscribe(()=> {this.canvas.drawFoobar()}).  How do I make Foobar an Observable?  Do I need to extend the Foobar Typescript class?

Once I get the "listening" to Foobar working (I am a good Java Swing programmer), how do I fire a Foobar changed event manually?  Suppose I modify Foobar and want to fire a modelChanged event (like in Swing) what is the pattern to do that in RxJS?

Please give me some hints andget me going in the right direction.  Is there a blog where RxJS is explained using Java Swing listening concepts?  Thank you and greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject). `this.foobar = new Subject<any>();`

Answer (score 1):

Subjects are RxJS's most common way to convert an imperative piece of code into functional RxJS streams. Subjects are both observers and observables so you can imperatively write `subject.next(value)` and also `subject.subscribe(value => {..})`

Here's a naive pattern that turns a property into a stream. Here, you wouldn't `subscribe` to `foobar`, you can instead `subscribe` to `_foobar` which is a `BehaviorSubject` representing the values being set on the property `foobar`

```
private _foobar$ = new BehaviorSubject<Foobar>(new Foobar(/*default*/));

get foobarProp(): Foobar {
  return this._foobar$.value
}

set foobarProp(val: Foobar): void {
  this._foobar$.next(val);
}
```

`this._foobar.next(val);` is not limited to a setter function. You can write that wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  I You got me going in the right direction and I got it to work.  For other with the same task, this is my solution (pardon the bad Typescript, I am starting out):

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { CanvasComponent } from './canvas/canvas.component';
import { Foobar } from './foobar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FOOOBAR';

  foobarSubject:BehaviorSubject<Foobar>;
  @ViewChild(CanvasComponent) canvasComponent:CanvasComponent;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngInit() called");
    this.foobarSubject= new BehaviorSubject<Forbar>(null);
    this.registerFoobar();
  }

  go() {
    this.foobarSubject.subscribe(
      (data:Foobar) => {
        if (data != null) {
          console.log("foobar was not null, updating canvas");          
          this.canvasComponent.update(data);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  // Register the callback containing the REST call 
  // so that it loads the next Foobar in the foobarSubject
  registerFoobar() {
    console.log("getting foobar");
    this.apiService.getFoobarObservable().subscribe(
      (foobar:Foobar) => {this.foobarSubject.next(foobar)},
      (err) => console.error(err),
      () => console.log("foobar: + this.foobarSubject.value.toString())
    );
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Hello {{title}}</h1>
<app-canvas></app-canvas>

<button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Go" title="Go"
(click)="go()">GO</button>
```

app.service.html

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Foobar } from './foobar';

    const remoteUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/foobar;
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getFoobarObservable(): Observable<Foobar> {
        return this.http.get<Foobar>(remoteUrl);
      }
    }
```